# Populate combobox inside DataGrid from database table

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have WPF DataGrid bound to an SQL server table, one of its columns is comboBox. I want to populate the comboBox from another table. For example: there are two tables - jobs and employees:

- employees has EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeJob_id
- jobs has JobID, JobName

Here is XAML:

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="241" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,20,0,0" Name="EmployeeDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EmployeeID" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="E_Name" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EmployeeJobID">
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding jobs_DataView, 
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="JobName" SelectedValuePath="JobID"
                                SelectedValue="EmployeeJobID"/>
                        </DataTemplate> 
                            
                               
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
 EmployeeDataGrid.DataContext = EmployeeDataView;
```

I also have a `DataView` for jobs table named `jobsDatView` which I want to use as items but no items are being added to the combobox.

Comment: You should make a view model class that is the data context for the whole window. It will have `EmployeeDataView` and `jobs_DataView` as properties. Do [some MVVM research](http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html), your question is not one question and is too broad for SO.